# Firebase realtime database saving data but not displaying it on console in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an application that requires a real time database. Firebase has been working fine with the application. The real time database is accessible through http post and get and are causing the firebase database to update its data on the console.

The problem is when I attempt to change data using flutter functions provided by the library.

```
    final firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Items");

    firebaseRef.set("hi");
    firebaseRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
    });
```

When i attempt to use the functions above the data seems to be available and the console prints Data: hi, but they do not appear on the firebase console when i check it online.

Any help is appreciated, I cant find any information that can help. I checked my set up 20 times and its correct, open to any suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like your application is not able to connect to the Firebase server. In such a situation the Firebase client keeps any local chance cached, and fires events for them usual, but it will only be able to synchronize those changes to the server once it establishes a connection again. If you're unable to determine whether the client is connection, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You were actually correct in assuming it was not connected. I checked the documentation you sent and it showed that i was not connected. If you can refer me to how i can troubleshoot the problem I would be grateful. The Firestore database is working fine, its just the real-time database that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the problem with the help of Frank van Puffelen, thanks man.
The problem was that the Firebase real-time database was not connected to the application and all the results i was getting were being cached on the device.

In case you run into a similar problem check whether the database is connected using the help of this part of the documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

In my case the reason it was not connected was because when referencing any real-time Database on flutter that is outside central America you need to place the url of the databse found in the firebase console in your code. As such:

```
final firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase(
        databaseURL:
            "https://yourfirebaseproject.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/")
    .reference()
    .child("Items");
```

I hope this is good enough to fix your problem.